# How do I achieve Caddy auto-TLS via Let's Encrypt without DNS?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot, caddy, caddyfile

I'm sure this is a typical scenario, but I can't find the appropriate sequence of steps.

I have a www.example.com server at (say) 1.1.1.1 running Apache. I am building a new server at 2.2.2.2 using Caddy. For testing, I put `2.2.2.2 www.example.com` in my local /etc/hosts. Once all is working, I will repoint the www.example.com DNS entry to Caddy.

The problem is I can't start Caddy on 2.2.2.2 to serve www.example.com.

I get 

`[www.example.com] failed to get certificate: acme: Error 403 - urn:acme:error:unauthorized - Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/6Xc4_oq6r0de25CtrYIw59YeVHvUWQ9Ag6H3XbGx8y0:`

which I assume is caused by the DNS entry for www.example.com pointing to 1.1.1.1, not 2.2.2.2

So how do I get certs and start Caddy so I can test www.example.com on 2.2.2.2 before updating the public DNS entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make up a new name for the test server, for example `test.example.com`.
2. Point the DNS A record for `test.example.com` to the same address as for `www.example.com`.
3. Get a Let's Encrypt certificate containing both names. Let's Encrypt lets you put how many names you want in the certificate.
4. Once you have the certificate, point the DNS A record for the test server to the new address. Now you can use the same certificate both in the production server and the test server.

Comment: cool. thx. At step 4, do I need to copy anything (cert?) from my live server to my test server?

Comment: You need to copy the certificate as part of the server configuration.

Comment: If you want a let's encrypt cert let caddy do it, but just wait until your site is live the turn on tls in your caddyfile

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you really should only use private IP's for test / trial sites.  You can use any of the following

- 10.x.x.x
- 192.168.x.x
- (there are also a few more)

so instead of

> 2.2.2.2 myexamplesite.com

use

> 10.2.2.2 myexamplesite.com

also and this answers your question, the caddy TLS using lets encrypt only works when the letencrypt site can access your site via the public ipaddress available from a DNS server that you don't control.  This is for very basic security purposes.

You can generate  self signed certificate and use that, but I'm afraid auto TLS with caddy is not possible the way you want.

Comment: Thanks Toby. I kinda guessed that. So what I'm asking is what is the recommended set of steps to allow me to test my caddy installation *before* switching over my live DNS. My two constraints (which don't seem unreasonable) are 1/ I want to thoroughly test the new server before making it live, and 2/ I don't want to disrupt the service availability to my existing live users.

Comment: Just don't switch on tls. Use tls off in your caddyfile server block